# Dynamically resize if hiding rows conditional in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm working on a report which displays a configuration for a product, which depending on the product choosen has specific properties. I thought it would be handy to have one rectangle with a table on the left (tblDetailsB) and one on the right side of the report (tblDetailsA) (don't mind the order of A and B here...).

Under the rectangle I have another table which shows a list of drawers (if they're part of the configuration), this list comes from another dataset.

[image: ssrs screenshot]

My problem is the size of the rectangle which holds tblDetailA and tlbDetailB is fixed (that's usually why one chooses a rectangle to hold..) and my tlbLade subreport for the drawers is under a lot of whitespace..

I could use subreports for tblDetailsA and tblDetailsB but I don't want to have too many of them..
I got myself into this mess, maybe someone knows a much better idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/hidden-rows-still-displayed-9660.shtml
I found out I have to suppress / hide the rows in the static row group under the details group (switch to advanced mode first..).
When I did that the size of the Rectangle (container) was ignored when the rows where hidden :)
[image: problem solved]

Regards,

Mike